# How can I find if the number of subsets for a list is very large?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to find the following;

```
Subsets[Range[2, 2300], {4}]
```

but my computer gave the following error:

> `Subsets::toomany:` The number of subsets (1160942293126) indicated by «input» is too large; it must be a machine integer."

What is your advice?

Comment: Do you really need to obtain all of the subsets?  Would a partial list suffice? E.g. subsets with at most `n` elements?  Or subsets with between `n` and `m` elements?  Or a "random" sampling of subsets?

Comment: That is a lot of subsets, but it definitely is a machine integer...

Comment: @DavidCarraher. my upper bound is 2300. i really need each subset of this expression, unfortunately.

Comment: do you have the memory required?

Comment: @Spawn1701D, For example, i have 4GB. is it enough ?

Comment: Assuming each list takes one byte you need 1160942293126B~1081GB ...

Comment: @Spawn1701D, Perhaps, i would have one day :)

Comment: @Nurettinırmak A list of 4 elements with your numbers takes 136 bytes. So for all the subsets, you'll need ~144 TB and change of memory. Good luck :)

Comment: @Nurettinırmak  Count me in too! :)

Comment: I wonder why there are 1160942293126 - I'd expect 1158922384830... (still quite some)

Comment: ah, the error msg is for `Subsets[Range[2,2300],{4}]` - nevermind then

Comment: @rm-rf, on my system ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger`` is $2^{31}-1$, which is considerably smaller than the number of subsets.

Comment: @SimonWoods Aaah... forgot about 32 bits :) Mine's 64

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9053/121

Answer (score 15):

Although this question is quite amusing, especially because of your *I have 4GB. is it enough?* comment, I think it is worth to give you some hints. Unfortunately, the number of subsets is so large, that even if you could create the subsets, it would be of no use because every calculation would need an incredible amount of time.

Let's say for simplicity you need all subsets of length 4 of `Range[2300]` then you would have to deal with `Binomial[2300, 4]` which is 1162964840675 subsets. Let's further assume you are a real deal in programming and your method needs only a millisecond to do whatever you like to do with each subset. The we still need about 35 years before you are done.

But to give you at least some advice, even if it will not help you with this problem. What you could do is *go through all subsets* instead of *creating all at once*. For this you only need an algorithm which can *count* through all subsets and on each subset you calculated what you need and step to the next.

One such algorithm can be found in Knuth's [The Art of Computer Programming Vol. 4, Fascicle 3](http://www.amazon.de/The-Computer-Programming-Vol-Fascicle/dp/0201853949). This algorithm can just be written down. Here with the rarely used *Mathematica* functions `Label` and `Goto` ;-)

So if you want to see a walk through all 4-subsets of `{0,...,99}` you could do

```
LexicographicCombinations[t_Integer, n_Integer] := Module[
   {c = Table[i, {i, 0, t + 1}], j = t, x = 0},
   c[[t + 1]] = n;
   c[[t + 2]] = 0;
   Label[T2];
   result = c[[1 ;; -3]];
   If[j > 0, x = j; Goto[T6];];
   Label[T3];
   If[c[[1]] + 1 < c[[2]],
    c[[1]]++; Goto[T2],
    j = 2
    ];
   Label[T4];
   c[[j - 1]] = j - 2;
   x = c[[j]] + 1;
   If[x == c[[j + 1]],
    j++;
    Goto[T4];
    ];
   Label[T5];
   If[j > t, Return[]];
   Label[T6];
   c[[j]] = x;
   j--;
   Goto[T2];
   ];
Dynamic[result]
LexicographicCombinations[4, 100]
```

Comment: +1 for the first half of the answer, but there is a much simpler way to generate the subsets, e.g. `Array[Subsets[Range[3, 2300], {4}, {#}] &, {10}, 15831808]`.  Faster is to generate in blocks, e.g.: `Subsets[Range[3, 2300], {4}, 1*^9 + {0, 9}]`

Comment: I am enthusiastically upvoting for two reasons: 1) TAOCP, 2) use of `Goto`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I needed this method in C once where unfortunately you don't have `Subsets` ;-) I prototyped it in *Mathematica* and I thought this is a good place to put it to show a use-case of a really nasty Goto/Label war.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, than you for your response. i will use your method. thanks..

Comment: OP might probably be interested in some of the functions *Combinatorica* has, like... oh, I don't know, `NextSubset[]` or `NextLexicographicSubset[]`.

Answer (score 10):

The number of subsets in your example is given by `Binomial[2299, 4]` and the largest machine integer on your system is `` Developer`$MaxMachineInteger ``, so a simple check if there are too many subsets is:

```
tooManySubsets = Binomial[2299, 4] > Developer`$MaxMachineInteger
(* True *)
```

Comment: This is `False` on 64-bit *Mathematica* 9. Of course, building the resulting list of subsets will still be impracticable due to its huge size regardless of the theoretical possibility of doing so on a sufficiently large machine.