# How can I revise my program to avoid "No more memory available"?

Tags: list-manipulation, memory

I have a program for calculating a type of list.

```
ff[num_Integer] := 
  Union[
    Select[Subsets[Tuples[Range[2 num], {2}], {num}], 
      Sort @ Flatten @ # == Sort @ Range[2 num] &], 
    SameTest -> (Sort[Sort /@ #1] == Sort[Sort /@ #2] &)];
```

Now, the problem is that `ff[num_]` doesn't work on my computer when `num >= 5`. I would really like to get `ff[8]`, even `ff[10]`. How can I change this program to use a better method for producing these types of list?

Comment: Have you tried analyzing your problem on paper before asking _Mathematica_ to crunch the numbers? For just $n=6$, you have roughly $\mathcal{O}(10^{10})$ elements, each containing 6 pairs... You can work out the memory required for that (and see how it becomes astronomically high for $n=10$). See [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23402/5) (possible duplicate)

Comment: All the solutions consist of a list beginning with 1, followed by permutations of Range[2,2n], such that the odd elements of the full lis increase monotonically.  This suggests an approach of producing the odd elements first (always beginning with 1), and then Riffle-ing with all permutations of the remaining elements, which are the Complement[Range[2, 2n], odd elements] .   I have to run so someone else can implement this if they wish.

Comment: I agree @Simon Woods. But as rm -rf mentioned, Orders will have also with [this nice solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k) unavoidable computational problems. The `Length` of the output list can be calculated with `Product[2*i-1,{i,1,num}]`. For `num=10` the length would be 654729075. At least this is for sure too much for my computer.